# Чем фреймворк отличается от среды разработки?

Tags: терминология

Чем фреймворк отличается от среды разработки? Что вообще входит в понятие фреймворка, а что им не является?

Answer (score 1):

Фреймворк - это такая большая библиотека с набором готовых инструментов и абстракций, которые часто требуются при разработке готового приложения.

Среда разработки - это программа, которая работает "в тесной связке" с языком программирования - как правило, в нее включена поддержка всех основных конструкций языка (например, по имени класса можно "перепрыгнуть" к его объявлению, какие-то выражения исполняются "на лету", например, подключение несуществующего файла помечается, как ошибка), она умеет компилировать / выполнять написанный код и проводить отладку.